# 4 Children: What is the probability that one of them has a birthday this month?

Tags: probability, statistics, matrix-equations

I want to know what the probability is given a family having 4 children, that one child has a birthday this month (at any given time)

How would this be expressed as an equation?

How do you account for the likelihood that 2 or more children have a birthday in the same month?

Lastly, can this be answered mathematically (and accurately) without knowing statistics about what percentage of the world is born in January, February, March, etc.?

This is not a homework assignment, this question arose when talking to my son about a family friend who has 4 children, it seems that one of them is always having a birthday.

Comment: The question cannot be answered without knowledge about actual distributions. The answer would be different for lambs than it is for people. And general statistics are not sufficient. Alice and Bob have $4$ children. Some might be twins. And the fact that Alice is away in Australia $10$ months of the year prospecting for gold should be taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

We want the probability that at-least one child has a birthday in June.

This is equivalent to the total probability, minus the probability that no child has a birthday in the month of June.

$$1-(\frac{11}{12})^4 = \frac{6095}{20736} = \text{approx} \;\;29.39\% $$

Note: This assumes that all of the children are born in each month equally likely. Hence without statistical research. User $André$ raises a very valid concern in regards to the possibility of doing such a problem without the above assumption.

Comment: Doesn't this assume that a kid is just as likely to be born any month of the year. Which may not necessarily be true, it may be that more kids are born in spring than summer thus you would have higher probability of being born in those months. I we dod assume one is just as likely than I agree with your answer

Comment: I like this answer because it addresses every part of the question.  I will wait a bit to encourage more answers, and then make a decision.

Comment: You also need to assume **independence** of the births in order for your answer to be valid. If you knew that two of them are twins, the calculation would be different (though the assumption "each month equally likely" still holds)

Comment: Another factor to consider is that all months aren't created equal. That isn't to say it would necessarily matter for this instance, but on a similar problem it could.